# which user answer is correct?

Tags: real-analysis

## Note:  Question pattern is same

Let $f\in C^1[-\pi,\pi]$ st $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)$ and define $$x_n=\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} f(t)\cos nt dt\,$$ for $n \in\Bbb{N}$ . Then does the sequence $\{nx_n\}$ converges? And does the series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} n^2|x_n|^2$ converges as $n\to \infty$.

I found   the  two  answer which creates  confusion in my mind

Here answer given below

[image]

Another  answer by Kavi  sir

[image]

Here im  confused  which one is most  correct answer...Im confuse that atmos  said that option $b)$ and $ c)$ is diverges while kavi sir is saying option $b)$ and $c)$ is converge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you require that $f(-\pi )=f(\pi )$, then the counterexample in the first answer does not work. In fact, if we use integration by parts, we have
$$
na_n =n\int_{-\pi }^{\pi } f(t)\cos nt\mathrm{d} t=-\int_{-\pi }^{\pi } f'(t)\sin nt\mathrm{d} t
$$
and hence it is the Fourier series of the function $f'$. Then **the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma** tells us that $na_n\rightarrow 0$ when $n\rightarrow\infty $.

For the second one, it's the **Plancherel's identity** implies to tell you that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }n^2\vert a_n\vert^2\leq\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{-\pi }^{\pi }\vert f'\vert^2\mathrm{d} t
$$
and hence the series is convergent.

**Remark** Periodicity plays an essential role in the proof, and the reason is, when the function $f$ is periodic, after integration by parts a term will vanish. In a higher point of view, when $f$ is periodic, it will be reduced to a function on the unit circle, so the integration will be the "real" Fourier coefficient of $f$.